# Determine $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} \frac{r}{n} u_{xx}(y)dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'd like to show

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} \frac{r}{n} u_{xx}(y)dy = \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{\partial B(x,r)}u_{xx}dS + (\frac{1}{n}-1)\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} u_{xx} dy$

where $\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-$ denotes the average of the integrale. Here $u = u(x,t) \in C^m(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty)), m\geq 2, n\geq 2$

Using the product rule I've gotten

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} \frac{r}{n} u_{xx}(y)dy = \frac{1}{n} \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} u_{xx}(y,t)dy + \frac{r}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} u_{xx}(y)dy$

and perhaps now I should use the differentiation formula for moving regions so:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)} u_{xx}(y)dy = \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{\partial B(x,r)}u_{xx}(y,t)\textbf{v}dS + \int\!\!\!\!\!\!-_{B(x,r)}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u_{xx}(y,t)dy$

but I'm not sure what $\textbf{v}$ should be or how to continue. If someone could help me out from there I'd appreciate it!

Comment: $$\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-$$ Use `\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-` or just write $\frac1{\omega_n r^n}$ in front of the integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substitution $y = rz + x$ to remove the dependence of the region on $r$ (also removing the multiplication by $r^{-n}$ coming from taking the average) - it will come out much tidier than using the differentiation formula for the moving boundary as $r$ will only appear in the integrand and nowhere else.

Comment: Does this mean that $B(x,r)$ becomes $B(x,1)$ and then the integral over $z$?

Comment: It becomes $B(0,1)$, and yeah integral over $z$ (with the lovely situation that $dy$ becomes $r^n dz$).